# SQL Server: SQL Server Agent not executing PowerShell script even though a success is reported

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-agent

I have a PowerShell script:

```
$date = (Get-Date -Format "yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss")
$file_name_headers= "path_string_"+$date+".csv"
$file_name_data = "path_string_"+$date+".csv"
bcp "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM db.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'name1' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo'" queryout $file_name_headers -S servername -t "," -T -c
bcp "db.dbo.name1" out $file_name_data -S servername -t "," -T -c
```

If I execute it line by line in PowerShell terminal it does what it is supposed to do. When I copy-paste it to a job step in SQL Server Agent and run the job, a success is reported but I cannot see any files that should be created with the script. I have successfully run other Agent jobs (executing stored procedures).

**EDIT:**

Permission issues. If the SQL Server rather than me uses the PowerShell to write to a file, the access is denied. I can use it to write to locations with sufficient permissions. And it was considered as a successful run simply because the bcp errors are not considered as script execution errors. The history of the job contained useful info.

Comment: You know that any path in here is local to the SQL Server? Are you checking locally on the SQL Server?

Comment: I do not think I understand. The file is supposed to be saved on a network drive. I use the full UNC name.

Comment: I haven't learnt Powershell yet but if you're using a UNC (I can't see one in your code) it should work or throw an error. Can you clarify: have you run this script interactively on the SQL Server?

Comment: The "path_string" includes a UNC name. I have opened the PowerShell terminal using MS SQL Server Management Studio and then executed the script line by line copying it and pasting into the terminal. It works. I then copy and paste the whole script into Agent job definition and it does nothing even tho a success is reported.

Comment: Is the computer you are are _running_ SQL Server Management Studio (and powershell) on, the same computer that you are _connecting_ to in SQL Server Management Studio in order to get to SQL Agent? I'm trying to work out if the jobs are actually running on a different server.

Comment: No. They are different. How can I verify that a PowerShell script would work when executed by the Server, then? How to debug it?

Comment: Remote on to the server and run it interactively

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the issue is what you've guessed at, a permissions issue related to the file operation. In my case, I was able to create a procedure that could access the file system. I was uncertain where exactly to modify the user account, so can't help you there. However, the common command to access the file system in a procedure is:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'DEL E:\folder\anotherfolder\*.txt'
```

Then you just run that procedure in the sql server agent job in tandem with scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I know this an old thread, but it happened yet again.  This time on SQL 2019.  Solution was to create a proxy in SQL Server to allow PowerShell to execute with proper permissions.  Normally SQL Agent jobs execute under the permissions of the account with which SQL Agent starts.  To work around this, under SQL Agent you can create a Proxy Account that can be used to execute SQL Agent jobs.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).